# Parser error "bad indentation of a mapping entry" in Swagger Editor

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

In the OpenAPI definition below, the parameter definition causes the parser error "bad indentation of a mapping entry". What is wrong?

```yaml
paths:
  /users/{username}:
    get:
      tags:
        - users
      summary: "Get the users profile"
      parameters:
       -in: path
        name: username  
        description: "get user by name"
        type: string
        required: true
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/users"
```

Answer (score 1):

In YAML sequences (lists), whitespace is required after the `-` indicator. You need to replace

```
-in: path
```

with

```
- in: path
```

(and align the subsequent keywords appropriately).